# How to determine what are the attribute necessary to add a plugin in pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

Since last few days a lot of doubts got cleared because of the you all experts. I have one more question, when i see my pom.xml in my project , I see a lot of plugins with quite a few  configuration. for e.g

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit-platform</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <argLine>${argLine} -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g</argLine>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

My question is how they decided the these forkcount , argLine needed to be used here? plus the dependency also. When i checked the bealdung doc for same plugin the config was very simple. is it necessary to read docs for a perticular plugin before using it. like how people take decisions for the same that what are the tags to be used or what are the mandatory tags. any links will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend reading the docs of the appropriate plugin which would show like in your example defining the provider (the dependency) https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/providers.html is usually not needed nor helpful/useful. For the other settings it depends on what kind of tests you are running but from my point of view I would strongly review my tests because needed to set 4 GiB for heapspace sounds weird .... especially for a tests? The others parts depends on the testing framework you are using.. and your use case. I usually start without any configuration for my builds ...only If i really need to change something I do so which is rarely the case. (Convention over configuration)... and read the docs: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise for your reply. I am not very much experienced in these so, i am trying to understand the POM and why it is so. i will read the docs and try to understand. moreover , i felt these all will come with experience when i will start building from scratch. all can not be understood reading only :)